# In Java how do I convert from seconds since epoch to milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, datetime-parsing

In short:

I have a time that is in epoch and I want to make it time since `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` as `java.util.Date` would expect to be given.

This code helps demonstrate my issue:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TimeHelp {

    private String format = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy";

    public SimpleDateFormat asSimpleDateFormat() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
    }

    public DateTimeFormatter asDateTimeFormatter() {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        String s = "Sun Apr 04 02:00:01 2010";
        long t1 = asSimpleDateFormat().parse(s).getTime();

        ZonedDateTime zoned = LocalDateTime.parse(s, asDateTimeFormatter())
                    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        long t2 = zoned.toEpochSecond() * 1000;

        long t3 = Date.from(zoned.toInstant()).getTime();

        long t4 = zoned.toInstant().toEpochMilli();

        System.out.println("t1 " + t1);
        System.out.println("t2 " + t2);
        System.out.println("t3 " + t3);
        System.out.println("t4 " + t4);
        System.out.println("Difference in minutes " + Math.abs(t1 - t2)/1000/60);
    } 
}
```

And that outputs:

```
Australia/Sydney
t1 1270310401000
t2 1270306801000
t3 1270306801000
t4 1270306801000
Difference in minutes 60
```

Note that t1 is different from all the others, I think because t1 is GMT while the others are all UTC.

If I use the `SimpleDateFormat` the value of the long is different to if I use the `DateTimeFormatter` to get a `ZonedDateTime` after which I call `toEpochSecond()`.

For reasons I would like to be given a `ZonedDateTime` and I want to convert that to a `Date` but it looks like such a thing wont work because the `Date` works in GMT not `UTC`.

Comment: `long t2 = zoned.toInstant().toEpochMilli();`

Comment: Updated question to include that, note that it gives `1270306801000` not `1270310401000`

Comment: Copy/paste error: `println("t4 " + t3);`

Comment: I hope that you are aware that `SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. You should use `DateTimeFormat` and `ZonedDateTime`. Also consider whether you really need milliseconds since the epoch. If you do, for full precision use `zoned.toInstant().toEpochMilli()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/australia/sydney?year=2010):

> When local daylight time was about to reach `Sunday, April 4, 2010, 3:00:00 am` clocks were turned backward 1 hour to `Sunday, April 4, 2010, 2:00:00 am` local standard time instead.

Which means that `Sun Apr 04 02:00:01 2010` happened **twice** that day. So which of those 2 do you get?

With `SimpleDateFormat` you get the *later* one, although that is undocumented.

With [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) you get the *earlier* one:

> For Overlaps, the general strategy is that if the local date-time falls in the middle of an Overlap, then the previous offset will be retained. If there is no previous offset, or the previous offset is invalid, then the earlier offset is used, typically "summer" time.. Two additional methods, `withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap()` and `withLaterOffsetAtOverlap()`, help manage the case of an overlap.